# Jasper Reports - Removing pageHeader/columnHeader from subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a master report with 2 subreports. I use the same report to generate PDF and xls. Pagination is enabled but for excel, i need to disable pagination, which i do by rendering all in one sheet. The page header/column header get repeat for each page. These page header/column header are from the sub reports. This is fine for PDF but in case of excel, i want to get rid of the repeating header. 
I set these properties:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.3" value="pageHeader" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.3" value="pageHeader" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="pageHeader" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1" value="columnHeader" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true" />
```

But these arent reflected in the data rendered by the subreport. In xls, i still see the pageHeader/columnHeader gets repeated. Please let me know, how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XLS (and HTML) reports, you may want to set the parameter IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION to true. See http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html for documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am generating pdf and excel at the same time and intend to fill it once and export them into required formats. But now i need to fill them separately for each export. But i will take the answer, which solves my problem. I still wondering why the properties are not getting applied to subreports.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I keep forgetting how to do this myself  and each time I search I seem to find this question so thought I'd put something so I find it next time.

In the main report file you also need to add the sub report to the filter:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1" value="columnHeader" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader" /> 
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.report.1" value="sub-report-name" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.1" value="sub-report-name" />
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works! Just a clarification: since the subreport tag doesn't accept the attribute "name", "sub-report-name" should always be replaced by the string "subreport".